# Powershell Get-ChildItem Check file name not working

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

What I want to do is look for particular files in a folder, then check the name of each file that macthes and drop it in another folder. Here is a sample of what I'm trying to do:

```
$FileABackupLoc = "C:\FolderA"
$FileBBackupLoc = "C:\FolderB"

Get-ChildItem -Path $SourceFolder -Include *Membership*.pgp -Name -Recurse | 
%{ 

    Write-Host "Current file: $_"

    if($_ -like '*FileA*')
    {
        [System.IO.FileInfo]$FileADestination = (Join-Path -Path $FileABackupLoc -ChildPath $_.Name.replace(“_”,“\”))
    move-item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $FileADestination.FullName -Verbose
   }

    if($_ -like '*FileB*')
    {
        [System.IO.FileInfo]$FileBDestination = (Join-Path -Path $FileBBackupLoc -ChildPath $_.Name.replace(“_”,“\”))
    move-item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $FileBDestination.FullName -Verbose
   }

}
```

When I run the code, I get this error but have no idea why:
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $SourceFolder -Include *Membership*.pgp -Recurse | % {

if ($_ -like '.*FileA.*')
{
  $FileADestination = Join-Path -Path $FileBBackupLoc -ChildPath (Split-Path -Leaf -Path $_.FullName)
  Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $FileADestination
}
...
```

I believe your use of the -Name argument in the original Get-ChildItem may be getting in your way here, from the docs:

> **-Name**
>
> Gets only the names of the items in the locations. If you pipe the output of this command to another command, only the item names are sent.

Comment: Yup, that was throwing me off!